# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm working in a project that detects plant disease with leaf images using PlantVillage dataset.

When I'm trying to predict the results using

```
image_dir="C:/Users/HP/Plant Disease Detection Using Deep Learning Approach/input/Potato___Early_blight/"

im=convert_image_to_array(image_dir)
np_image_li = np.array(im, dtype=np.float16) / 225.0
npp_image = np.expand_dims(np_image_li, axis=0)
result=model.predict(npp_image)
```

I' getting an error

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 0)

I have built the model using

```
aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=25, width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, 
    zoom_range=0.2,horizontal_flip=True, 
    fill_mode="nearest")

model = Sequential()
inputShape = (height, width, depth)
chanDim = -1
if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
    inputShape = (depth, height, width)
    chanDim = 1
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(n_classes))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

Comment: That's the image generator, not the model. Also can you add some more details on the shapes of the images?

Comment: `history = model.fit_generator(
    aug.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1
    )`

Comment: Have you checked the shapes of your images?

Comment: yes it is [256,256]

Comment: Hi @AzeezFazry, there could be an error in the convert_image_to_array function. It would be helpful if you could add the code related to it so that we can help you better. Please refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/5c614a1a285ebaf55d4d1312fec467ca/72687939.ipynb) where I tried to run the model without any errors. Thank you!